# how to deploy an application PyQT (QML)

Tags: deployment, pyqt, qml

I succeeded to developed a small application under Windows using PyQT and QML, and now I will like to use it in a tablet (windows).
Then I have no idea how to do the deployed (I want have an icon in my tablet, when I click on it.... the application starts)
I've heard of pydepolyer or py2exe that generates .exe but I do not know how to use it.

this is the architecture of my application.

```
> projet
........projet.pro
........>Sources
..............main.py
........>Ressources
................>qml.qrc
.....................>content
..........................Etale.qml
......................main.qml
......................Page.qml
......................Page1.qml
```

thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python has a nice little comparison table of freezing tools with links to their manuals.[image]

[Freezing your code](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shipping/freezing/)

I've used both py2exe and pyInstaller. I found that while more difficult to use, in the long run, pyInstaller has more features that are more appealing.

There is also a [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Deploying_PyQt_Applications) dedicated to packaging and deploying PyQt applications.